# Nested gapply(), dapply, or spark_apply() function?

Tags: r, apache-spark, cluster-computing, sparkr, sparklyr

I have two separate Hive tables within which I'd like to run a very complex string matching algorithm. I'd like to use SparkR or sparklyr, but I'm trying to determine the feasibility of nested `dapply`, `gapply`, or `spark_apply` statements. I haven't seen a single example of a nested apply.

The problem statement: Fuzzy matching on addresses within zip codes. Essentially, I've already done a cartesian join on addresses from both data sets where Zip=Zip. But now I have two columns of Addresses that need to be matched, and an third column of Zips that need to be retained as a "GroupBy" to constrain the superset of potential pairwise comparisons. Thus, the first "key" is the Zip, but then I want to use a second "key" to send a series of comparisons to a single address from column1, matching all possible addresses in column2 (within the same Zip). This seems to require one of the distributed `apply` functions within `SparkR` or `sparklyr`, but each of them does not look like it will allow, for example, `gapply(...,gapply())` or `spark_apply(...,spark_apply())`.

Has anyone every tried this or gotten around a similar problem?

Comment: Nothing like this is allowed by design. The answer is join or (in the worst case scenario) crossProduct

Comment: Already ran the crossProduct... Still need to run attempts at fuzzy matches within Zips... otherwise there are no efficiencies. I don't want to write a new RDD for each "within-zip" set of crossProduct addresses. When imagining the DAG, it feels obvious that there should be a way to set this up. But it feels intractable within the SparkR context...?